# How to access the gapi.auth2 on fresh reload in reactjs to check if the user is already logged in?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-signin, google-api-js-client

I need to maintain the login session in react js when I login through google using the react-google-login

I have created an Login component, inside which I am rendering the GoogleLogin component provided by 'react-google-login'.

I am calling my Login component inside my header component.

Everything related to login is set up and working fine, but the issue is as I reload the page the user gets logged out as the state is set to initial state.

I assumed, it can be done through gapi object which is available globally on window. (I have already added the script tag for google api inside head of my html file)

but when I try to do this - let auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();

I get that auth2 is not defined. 
however gapi is defined as I can see it when I log it on console.

I can also access the auth2 obect once I click on Login button inside the loginsuccess callback but not before.

So, I have below questions.

Am I on the right way ? 
if yes, then how do I proceed?

if not, what should I do to maintain the google login session in react?

```
class Login extends React.Component{
      constructor(props){
       super(props)
       console.log(gapi);  // gapi is available
       let auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();  // auth2 is not accessible here 
     }


    responseGoogle = (response) => {
      let auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();  // auth2 is accessible here 
      let id_token = response.getAuthResponse().id_token;
      let profile = response.getBasicProfile();
      console.log(this);

// api call here to validate the token on the backend which works fine

      fetch();  
}
render(){

        return(<GoogleLogin
            clientId="CLIENT_ID"
            buttonText="Login"
            onSuccess={this.responseGoogle}
            onFailure={this.responseGoogle}
            cookiePolicy={'single_host_origin'}
          />);
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  ...state
 })

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  setLoginInfo: (content) => dispatch(upDateLogin(content))
 })

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can store your authentication code which can be used to get refresh code and access code**.

You can generate `access token` if the expiration time expires!

1. First get the `authentication code`.
2. Get `refresh_token` from google
   using authentication code.
3. Get `access_token` using `refresh_token` when
   it expires.

> I assume that you have the authentication code. If you do not have the
> code then here is an [article](https://medium.com/@sacshaurov05/login-with-google-oauth-get-refresh-and-access-token-regenerate-access-token-on-your-react-app-101677118ac7) on how you can integrate oauth to
> your react app and get the authentication code from google. You can
> check this out for more details.

**Generating refresh and access token:**

Replace the essential values (`code`, `client_id`, `client_secret`) inside payload.

```
let payload = {
  grant_type: 'authorization_code',
  code: '****SFJSDFJKAN-DF',
  client_id: '******.googleusercontent.com',
  client_secret: 'GOCS*******m5Qzg',
  redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000',
};

axios
  .post(`https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token`, payload, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;',
    },
  })
  .then((res: any) => {
    return res.data;
  })
  .then((response: any) => {
    console.log('refresh token: ', response);
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log('err: ', err));
```

You will get a response like this:

```
{
    access_token: "********KAjJZmv4xLvbAIHey",
    expires_in: 3599,
    id_token: "***************VeM7cfmgbvVIg",
    refresh_token: "***************VeM7cfmgbvVIg",
    scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly openid 
            .....
            .....
            https://mail.google.com/",
    token_type: "Bearer",
}
```

Save your refresh and access token.
Now you can use refresh token to generate new access token!

**Generate new access token from refresh token.**

```
let payloadForAccessToken = {
  grant_type: 'refresh_token',
  refresh_token: '*******SFKNSK***',
  client_id: '******.googleusercontent.com',
  client_secret: '*****cxCsrf***8UUm5Qzg',
};

axios
  .post(`https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token`, payloadForAccessToken, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;',
    },
  })
  .then((res: any) => {
    return res.data;
  })
  .then((res) => {
    console.log('new token response: ', res);
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log('err: ', err));
```

Store `access_token` and `refresh_token` on your local storage or backend. But I would recommend encrypting the tokens. Using these tokens, you can get the user profile or other informations. When the user logs out, then remove these tokens from local storage or backend.